# Project Server - Copy timesheet from previous week

Tags: project-server

Code share, and looking for better solution.
1. use ribbon bar button to call the page by ajax.
2. reload current page.

Question: 
1. After the queueSvc return JobState.Success, the timesheet still not available, we had to uglily wait another 10 seconds before reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
private const int QUEUE_WAIT_TIME = 1;

private bool IsDebug {
    get {
        return Request.Params["debug"] == "1";
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);
    try {
        int result = Process();
        Response.Write(String.Format("{{\"result\": {0}}}", result));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        SPLogger.Error(ex);
        Response.Write(String.Format("{{\"result\": 0, \"error\": \"{0}\"}}", ex.Message.Replace("\"", "'")));
    }
}

protected int Process() {
    Guid? periodId = null;
    DateTime? currentDt = null;
    DateTime? periodStart = null;
    DateTime? periodFinish = null;
    Guid? timesheetId = null;
    Guid jobId, managerId;
    string timesheetName = String.Empty;
    TimesheetDataSet currDS, prevDS;

    if (Request.Params["tsDate"] != null) {
        try { currentDt = SPUtility.ParseDate(SPContext.Current.Web, Request.Params["tsDate"], "", false); } catch { }
    }

    if (Request.Params["tsUID"] != null) {
        try { timesheetId = new Guid(Request.Params["tsUID"]); } catch { }
    }

    if (Request.Params["tsPRD"] != null) {
        try { periodId = new Guid(Request.Params["tsPRD"]); } catch { }
    }

    TimeSheet tsSvc = new TimeSheet();
    tsSvc.Url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_vti_bin/psi/timesheet.asmx";
    tsSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    Resource resSvc = new Resource();
    resSvc.Url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_vti_bin/psi/resource.asmx";
    resSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    Admin adminSvc = new Admin();
    adminSvc.Url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_vti_bin/psi/admin.asmx";
    adminSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    QueueSystem queueSvc = new QueueSystem();
    queueSvc.Url = SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_vti_bin/psi/queuesystem.asmx";
    queueSvc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    Guid userId = resSvc.GetCurrentUserUid();

    if (timesheetId.HasValue) {
        // if tsUID is declared
        periodId = GetPeriodIdByTimesheetDataSet(tsSvc.ReadTimesheet(timesheetId.Value));
    }

    TimePeriodDataSet periodDS = adminSvc.ReadPeriods(PeriodState.All);
    if (!currentDt.HasValue) { currentDt = DateTime.Now; }

    for (int i = 0; i < periodDS.TimePeriods.Count; i++) {

        if (periodId.HasValue) {
            // if tsPRD/tsUID is declared
            if (periodId.Value.Equals(periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_UID)) {
                periodStart = periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_START_DATE;
                periodFinish = periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_FINISH_DATE;
                break;
            }
        } else if ((currentDt.Value.Ticks > periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_START_DATE.Ticks) && (currentDt.Value.Ticks < periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_FINISH_DATE.Ticks)) {
            periodStart = periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_START_DATE;
            periodFinish = periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_FINISH_DATE;
            periodId = periodDS.TimePeriods[i].WPRD_UID;
            break;
        }
    }

    try {
        prevDS = tsSvc.ReadTimesheetByPeriod(userId, periodId.Value, PRU.PS.Web.TimesheetWebSvc.Navigation.Previous);
        if (IsDebug) PrintTimesheet(prevDS, "before: previous");
        if (prevDS == null || prevDS.Headers.Rows.Count < 1) return -1;
    } catch (Exception iex) {
        SPLogger.Error("error retrieving previous timesheet", iex);
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        currDS = tsSvc.ReadTimesheetByPeriod(userId, periodId.Value, PRU.PS.Web.TimesheetWebSvc.Navigation.Current);
        if (IsDebug) PrintTimesheet(currDS, "before: current");
        if (currDS == null || currDS.Headers.Rows.Count < 1) return -2;
    } catch (Exception iex) {
        SPLogger.Error("error retrieving current timesheet", iex);
        return -2;
    }

    managerId = (Guid)prevDS.Headers.Rows[0][prevDS.Headers.RES_TIMESHEET_MGR_UIDColumn];
    timesheetId = (Guid)currDS.Headers.Rows[0][currDS.Headers.TS_UIDColumn];

    timesheetName = String.Format("Timesheet {0}-{1}", 
        SPUtility.FormatDate(SPContext.Current.Web, periodStart.Value, SPDateFormat.DateOnly),
        SPUtility.FormatDate(SPContext.Current.Web, periodFinish.Value, SPDateFormat.DateOnly));

    try {
        // delete existing timesheet
        if (currDS.Headers.Rows.Count > 0) {
            timesheetId = (Guid)currDS.Headers.Rows[0][currDS.Headers.TS_UIDColumn];
            jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
            tsSvc.QueueDeleteTimesheet(jobId, timesheetId.Value);
            WaitForQueue(queueSvc, jobId, "QueueDeleteTimesheet");
        } else {
            SPLogger.Debug("Current period timesheet not exist");
        }
    } catch (Exception iex) {
        SPLogger.Error(iex);
        return -3;// error when delete existing timesheet
    }

    // create new timesheet
    timesheetId = PrepareEmptyTimesheet(tsSvc, userId, managerId, periodId.Value, timesheetName);
    currDS = tsSvc.ReadTimesheet(timesheetId.Value);

    // copy value to new timesheet
    List<Guid> lineIds = new List<Guid>();
    foreach (DataRow row in prevDS.Lines.Rows) {
        TimesheetDataSet.LinesRow p_line = (TimesheetDataSet.LinesRow)row;

        TimesheetDataSet.LinesRow n_line = currDS.Lines.NewLinesRow();
        n_line.TS_UID = timesheetId.Value;
        n_line.TS_LINE_UID = Guid.NewGuid();
        n_line.TS_LINE_CLASS_UID = p_line.TS_LINE_CLASS_UID;
        n_line.TS_LINE_COMMENT = p_line.TS_LINE_COMMENT;
        n_line.TS_LINE_CACHED_ASSIGN_NAME = p_line.TS_LINE_CACHED_ASSIGN_NAME;
        n_line.TS_LINE_CACHED_PROJ_NAME = p_line.TS_LINE_CACHED_PROJ_NAME;
        n_line.TS_LINE_VALIDATION_TYPE = p_line.TS_LINE_VALIDATION_TYPE;
        n_line.TS_LINE_STATUS = p_line.TS_LINE_STATUS;

        if (!p_line.IsASSN_UIDNull()) n_line.ASSN_UID = p_line.ASSN_UID;

        currDS.Lines.AddLinesRow(n_line);
        lineIds.Add(n_line.TS_LINE_UID);
        tsSvc.PrepareTimesheetLine(timesheetId.Value, ref currDS, new Guid[] { n_line.TS_LINE_UID });

        var b = from a in prevDS.Actuals.AsEnumerable()
                        where ((TimesheetDataSet.ActualsRow)a).TS_LINE_UID.Equals(p_line.TS_LINE_UID)
                        select (TimesheetDataSet.ActualsRow)a;

        foreach (TimesheetDataSet.ActualsRow p_actual in b) {

            TimesheetDataSet.ActualsRow n_actual = currDS.Actuals.FindByTS_LINE_UIDTS_ACT_START_DATE(n_line.TS_LINE_UID, p_actual.TS_ACT_START_DATE.AddDays(7));

            if (n_actual != null) {
                n_actual.TS_ACT_PLAN_VALUE = p_actual.TS_ACT_PLAN_VALUE;
                n_actual.TS_ACT_VALUE = p_actual.TS_ACT_VALUE;
                SPLogger.Debug("Update existing Actual Row");
            } else {
                n_actual = currDS.Actuals.NewActualsRow();
                n_actual.TS_LINE_UID = n_line.TS_LINE_UID;
                n_actual.TS_ACT_START_DATE = p_actual.TS_ACT_START_DATE.AddDays(7);
                n_actual.TS_ACT_FINISH_DATE = p_actual.TS_ACT_FINISH_DATE.AddDays(7);
                n_actual.TS_ACT_PLAN_VALUE = p_actual.TS_ACT_PLAN_VALUE;
                n_actual.TS_ACT_VALUE = p_actual.TS_ACT_VALUE;
                SPLogger.Debug(String.Format("New Actual Row added: id={0},start={1},finish={2},plan={3},actual={4}", n_actual.TS_LINE_UID, n_actual.TS_ACT_START_DATE, n_actual.TS_ACT_FINISH_DATE, n_actual.TS_ACT_PLAN_VALUE, n_actual.TS_ACT_VALUE));
                currDS.Actuals.AddActualsRow(n_actual);
            }
        }

    }

    jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
    tsSvc.QueueUpdateTimesheet(jobId, timesheetId.Value, currDS);
    WaitForQueue(queueSvc, jobId, "QueueUpdateTimesheet");
    SPLogger.Debug("Copy timesheet finished");
    return 1; // success
}

private Guid? GetPeriodIdByTimesheetDataSet(TimesheetDataSet tsDS) {
    return (tsDS.Headers.Rows.Count > 0) ? (Guid?)tsDS.Headers.Rows[0][tsDS.Headers.WPRD_UIDColumn] : null;
}

private Guid PrepareEmptyTimesheet(TimeSheet tsSvc, Guid resourceId, Guid managerId, Guid periodId, string timesheetName) {
    SPLogger.Debug(String.Format("resId={0},mgrId={1},prdId={2}", resourceId, managerId, periodId));
    TimesheetDataSet tsDS = new TimesheetDataSet();
    TimesheetDataSet.HeadersRow header = tsDS.Headers.NewHeadersRow();
    header.RES_UID = resourceId;
    header.TS_UID = Guid.NewGuid();
    header.WPRD_UID = periodId;
    header.TS_NAME = timesheetName;
    header.TS_COMMENTS = String.Empty;
    header.TS_CREATOR_RES_UID = resourceId;
    header.TS_ENTRY_MODE_ENUM = 0; //TimesheetEnum.EntryMode.Daily;
    tsDS.Headers.AddHeadersRow(header);

    // Create the timesheet with the default line types that are specified by the admin.
    tsSvc.CreateTimesheet(tsDS, PreloadType.None);
    return header.TS_UID;       
}

private void WaitForQueue(QueueSystem queueSvc, Guid jobId, string jobName) {
    JobState state;
    bool done = false;
    string xmlError = string.Empty;

    SPLogger.Debug(String.Format("Job:{0} submitted, waiting on queue, estimate: {1} seconds", jobName, queueSvc.GetJobWaitTime(jobId)));

    do {
        state = queueSvc.GetJobCompletionState(jobId, out xmlError);
        if (state == JobState.Success) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            if (state == JobState.Unknown
                || state == JobState.Failed
                || state == JobState.FailedNotBlocking
                || state == JobState.CorrelationBlocked
                || state == JobState.Canceled) {
                    SPLogger.Error("Queue request error:" + xmlError);
                    throw new Exception(xmlError);
            } else {
                SPLogger.Debug("Sleep...");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(QUEUE_WAIT_TIME * 1000);
            }
        }
    } while (!done);
}
```